# Trying to convert rows to columns using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webforms, dataset

Below is my code which I am using

```
private DataTable GenerateTransposedTable(DataTable inputTable)
{
    DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();
    // Add columns by looping rows
    // Header row's first column is same as in inputTable
    outputTable.Columns.Add(inputTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());
    // Header row's second column onwards, 'inputTable's first column taken
    foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
    {
        string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
        DataColumnCollection columns = outputTable.Columns;
        if (!columns.Contains(newColName))//code to check duplication of columns
        {
            outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
        }
    }
    // Add rows by looping columns        
    for (int rCount = 1; rCount <= inputTable.Columns.Count - 1; rCount++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();
        // First column is inputTable's Header row's second column
        newRow[0] = inputTable.Columns[rCount].ColumnName.ToString();
        for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= inputTable.Rows.Count - 1; cCount++)
        {
            string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
            //int rowcount = cCount + 1;
            //if (cCount <= rowcount)
            //{
            newRow[cCount + 1] = colValue; //**Error here when starts second record**
            //}
        }
        outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    //for (int i = outputTable.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        for (int j = 0; j < outputTable.Columns.Count;j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < outputTable.Rows.Count; k++)
            {
                string sdfsdf = outputTable.Rows[k][j].ToString();
                if (outputTable.Rows[k][j].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    DataRow dr = outputTable.Rows[k];
                    dr.Delete();
                }

            }

        }
        outputTable.AcceptChanges();
    return outputTable;
}
```

Below is the format data I am getting from xml which I am converting to dataTable as below:

```
 dataTable
 **Columnname               value**
 CANDIDATEID                3215456454454
 Last Name                  demo1
 Email                      demo1@gmail.com
 Mobile                     0000000
 Experience in Years        null
 Current Employer           null
 CANDIDATEID                2515456564
 Last Name                  demo2
 Email                      test@gmail.com
 Mobile                     354564654
 Experience in Years        null
 Current Employer           null
```

I need output like below :column names (for sample I specified only some columns here I need all the columns which i am getting in datatable).

```
 CandidateId           Last Name                Email              Mobile  etc
 3215456454454           demo1                 demo1@gmail.com      00000000
 2515456564              demo2                  test@gmail.com       354564654
```

Comment: are the column names dynamic? i.e in the left most column of first table? Or are they always the same?

Comment: column names iam getting from a zoho recruit API in a XML string which iam converting it into datatable when i convert into datatable iam getting the previous post format but iwant in    CandidateId           Last Name                Email   Mobile            
 3215456454454           demo1                 demo1@gmail.com      00000000
 2515456564              demo2                  test@gmail.com       354564654

Comment: yes column names are dynamic

Comment: You don't need to convert it to datatable in that case. You can convert to an object, I can add this as answer if you would like

Comment: I can post dynamic datatable answer and object answer. Give me some time to sort. Quiet in work haha

Comment: yes please do it. @SeanT

Comment: I am waiting for your reply. @SeanT

Comment: working on it mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's what I have, you will need to test. I htink it is best for you to convert your xml to an object but that is another question.

This will work for any data so if your xml changes then this will still work.

```
public DataTable convertTable(DataTable inputTable, int columnNameIndex = 0, int columnValueIndex = 1)
    {
        var outputTable = new DataTable();

        //Get the names of the columns for the output table
        var columnNames = inputTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x[columnNameIndex] != DBNull.Value && x[columnValueIndex] != DBNull.Value)
                                                        .Select(x => x[columnNameIndex].ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
        DataRow outputRow = outputTable.NewRow();

        //create the columns in the output table
        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            outputTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(columnName));
        }

        //get all the rows in the input table
        var totalRows = inputTable.Rows.Count;

        //loop through the input table
        for (int n = 0; n < totalRows; n++)
        {
            //loop through each columnname for each row
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++)
            {
                //if it's the first loop we need a new row
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    outputRow = outputTable.NewRow();
                }

                outputRow[columnNames[i]] = inputTable.Rows[n][columnValueIndex].ToString();
                   //^^get the corresponding value from the input table
                
                //if it's the last loop all columns 
                //have values added so add the row to the input table
                if (i == columnNames.Count - 1)
                    outputTable.Rows.Add(outputRow);

            }
        }

        return outputTable;
}
```

Comment: OK thank you, I will check and mark you as a answer after confirmation. @Sean T

Comment: I have made an edit - did not notice that the line to get value into output table was in conditional `if(i==0){}`